# Segmentation fault on isdigit function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to check that the third command line is a digit so I did

```
int n;
if (!isdigit(argv[3]))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "n MUST be a number");
        return 4;
    } else 
    {
        n = atoi(argv[3]);
        printf("%i\n",n);
    }
```

but I'm getting

```
Segmentation fault
```

however if I just did

```
int n = atoi(argv[3]);
```

it works just fine, I don't really understand why

Comment: `isdigit` expects an `int`, you are feeding it a `char*`. Turn on warnings.

Comment: Where do you check `argc >= 4`?

Comment: `if (!isdigit(argv[3][0]) || (argv[3][0] == '-' && !isdigit(argv[3][1])))` Also third command line is maybe `argv[2]` (1st : argv[0], 2nd : argv[1], 3rd : argv[2])

Comment: Can't you do: try { int n = atoi(argv[3]); } catch(whateverError) {cout << "Not a number" }?

Comment: @OmidCompSCI What? No, this is C. Plus, even if it was C++, `isdigit` doesn't throw.

Comment: @DeiDei oops sorry its C. And wouldn't there be some integer conversion error or something?

Comment: `sscanf` would work here. Assuming the argument exists, `if(sscanf(argv[3], "%d", &n) != 1) { fprintf(stderr, "n MUST be a number"); }`

Comment: @OmidCompSCI: There would be if you included the appropriate header file to get a declaration for `isdigit`, or if you enabled `-Werror=implicit-function-declaration` to prevent the compiler from accepting invalid code that tries to call a function without declaring it.

Comment: @DeiDei okay, so I changed it to convert atoi first then it checks, the problem now is that the if is always evaluated to true

Comment: Use `strtol()` instead so that you can find out if there was an error.

Comment: @R.. cool thanks. Is this good programming practice if it was C++, to include this header file and use try catch? Or is it too complicated for a simple task?

Comment: @OmidCompSCI: C (as well as C++) **requires** a declaration for any function you use, and for standard functions you *usually* need to include the standard header to get one. A compiler that silently accepts a program missing declarations is a buggy compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DeiDei in the comments is right. Have a look at the way argv is declared:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
```

It's an array of pointers, where each pointer points to a C string, i.e. an array of characters. So `argv[3]` is a pointer to the first character of the third argument. (Arrays start from 0, but argv[0] is the name of your program).

isdigit() is declared like this:

```
int isdigit(int c);
```

So it's expecting an int, not a pointer. You'll need to dereference the pointer you're sending to isdigit, like this:

```
isdigit(*argv[3])
```

(Remember that in C, a char is a special case of int, so the compiler is ok with this.)

Comment: Thanks man that's fixed my problem and my understanding haha :)

Answer (score 3):

From man isdigit:
`int isdigit(int c)`. But `argv[3]` is `char*` (address to char), so there is a mismatch.  Further

> The value of the argument must be representable as an unsigned char or the value of EOF.

As `argv[3]` may not be representable as an uchar, the behaviour is undefined, and you may get a segmentation violation.